# EF 6 tries to change unexisting table on Add-Migration / Update-Database

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm doing the command :
PM> Add-Migration test 
and here is generated migration:
`

```
public partial class test : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            MoveTable(name: "dbo.AccountToken", newSchema: "cns");
...
```

but the issue I don't have AccountToken table anywhere (checked with: `Select * from sys.tables where name like '%account%'` )

The error is: *'Cannot find the object 'AccountToken', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.'*

Thanx in advance

Comment: Sure, I can resolve by adding a table manually, but I do that on our from-amazon copy-of-live, and we're building automated migrations, so it is possible to meet an issue on live

Comment: Comment that line out, apply the migration and you won't see it in the future. Otherwise look for a reference in your models.

Comment: I can name it we have some "hidden" table, so I'm not sure that will work good on live. Trying to dig in to find a problem.